# KeyBinding Label

Tags: c#, wpf, inputbinding

I have a `TreeView` with the following definition:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="tree">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" >
                <Label.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="Delete"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                </Label.InputBindings>
            </Label>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

This view is boud to it's Code-Behind-File with:

`DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

The `InputBinding` for the `LeftDoubleClick` just works fine.

But the `InputBinding` for the 'Delete'-Key doesn't work.

The `Command` where the `KeyBinding` is bound to looks like:

```
public ICommand DeleteFolderCommand
{
    get { return _deleteFolderCommand; }
    set
    {
        _deleteFolderCommand = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and in the constructor I define:

```
DeleteFolderCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteFolder);
```

and the DeleteFolder-Method just looks like:

```
private void DeleteFolder(object parameter)
{
  // Break-Point here will not be reached                
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've already checked the Output-Window for Binding-Errors, but there are none.

Comment: binding looks ok at first glance. does SelectFolderCommand work? and is DeleteFolderCommand exists in the same VM as SelectFolderCommand?

Comment: Yes, the `SelectFolderCommand` works fine. And the `DeleteFolderCommand` is in the same `ViewModel`

Comment: at this point you can check if the `Delete` key is not being consumed anywhere. and the item is in focus when you press delete

Comment: i think this is the problem,keybinding on label does not work

Comment: Wrap the label around a contentcontrol and use the input bindings on the contentcontrol instead.

Comment: The solution with the `ContentControl` doesn't work either

Comment: Can you use snoop and see if the input bindings are getting handled somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it by handling the `KeyBinding` directly at the `TreeView`

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="tree">
    <TreeView.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </TreeView.InputBindings>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}">
                <Label.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectFolderCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                </Label.InputBindings>
            </Label>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```